# Check if list contains value javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript.
This is my codes, I want it to return true if it finds 'anna' in the list

```
var userList = [{'username':'anna','email':'anna@a.c'},
               {'username':'benny','email':'benny@a.c'},
               {'username':'kathy','email':'kathy@a.c'}]

return userList.includes('anna')
```

your help it much appreciated

Answer (score 6):

Use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

ES6 syntax:

```
return userList.some(user => user.username === 'anna');
```

ES5 syntax:

```
function hasAnna(user) {
  return user.username === 'anna';
}
return userList.some(hasAnna);
```

Comment: `.some()` is cool, just note that IE does not support Arrow functions.

Comment: @PHPglue good point. I've updated the answer. I kind of assume that everyone uses babel these days :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
return userList.filter(function(e,i) { return e.username == 'anna' }).length > 0;
```

What this is doing is filtering the array, `userList`, for all entries with a `username` value of `'anna'` and returning whether or not that filtered list has a length greater than 0 (i.e. has at least one entry).

Comment: While this will work, it's a bit inefficient... Imagine that you have a long list of thousand of items and there is one item that contains 'anna' in the second position. The solution that you are suggesting will iterate through all the items (even if 'anna' was found in the second position). Using `some` the execution will stop at the second one. I'm giving you a plus one anyways because your answer solves the problem.

Comment: Wouldn't a strict comparison using `===` be more fitting in this case?